# Validator for composite component validates, but also throws exception

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I want to attach validator to composite component, and I want it to be attached to every child component inside:

```
<cc:interface>
  <cc:attribute name="validator"
                method-signature="void f(javax.faces.context.FacesContext,
                                         javax.faces.component.UIComponent,
                                         java.lang.Object)"
                targets="child1 child2"/>
  <cc:editableValueHolder name="child1"/>
  <cc:editableValueHolder name="child2"/>
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
  <h:inputText id="child1"/>
  <h:inputText id="child2"/>
</cc:implementation>
```

So on page I have:

```
<xxx:mycomponent validator="#{bean.validationMethod}"/>
```

Validation works as expected, but JSF also throws a message: 
`..../form.xhtml validator="#{bean.validationMethod}": The class 'my.package.Bean' does not have the property 'validationMethod'.`

How can I get rid of this message?

Comment: I assume that the missing `{` and `bean.` is just a typo :) What JSF impl/version? I haven't seen this one before.

Comment: What's JSF version? Don't know, it's in JBossAS 6 CR1.